# Find the first empty column after the given row Excel VBA, VBA Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My code is as below for copying and pasting data from source sheet (copy.xlsm) to another sheet (paste.xlsm). It works good until to the G column which has formula. I couldn't run this vba to paste data to H column because of "VBA Error 1004 – Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error". Can anyone help me with it? Thank you.

```
Sub CopyPasteData()
Dim src As Worksheet, DestNJ As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long , LRNJ As Long

Set src = Workbooks("Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("S_TOTAL")

'NJ
Set DestNJ = Workbooks("Paste.xlsx").Worksheets("NJ")
DestNJ.Activate

lastCol = DestNJ.Cells(2, DestNJ.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   
For i = 1 To lastCol
    If DestNJ.Cells(2, i) = "" Then
        LRNJ = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i


src.Range("C3:C6").Copy
DestNJ.Cells(2, LRNJ).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

src.Range("D3:D6").Copy
DestNJ.Cells(8, LRNJ).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Here is the example of my data set.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg4Lz.png)

Comment: What does `Debug.Print LRNJ` output in the Immediate Window? Likely 0.

Comment: Yes, it is 0. And I have revised those dim but still don't work.

Comment: Then `If DestNJ.Cells(2, i) = "" Then` is never True. You're getting an error because there is no column 0, but you're trying to use `LRNJ`, which has a value of 0, with `Cells`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't know why it is 0 when the cell has formula.

Comment: What is a sample formula? Does it return `""`?

Comment: The formula is "=SUM(B2:F2)".  I thought the lastCol would be "G" after pasting data to the "F" column. So the LRNJ would be 7.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you BigBen pointed out the problem.

I have revised the if loop and it works now.

```
For i = 1 To lastCol
    If DestNJ.Cells(2, i) = "" Then
        LRNJ = i
        Exit For
    ElseIf i = lastCol Then
        LRNJ = i + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```